# Set_Index Inconsistent KeyError

Tags: python, dataframe, set, yahoo-finance

I specifically need help understanding why this code works one minute, and then the next it does not. ***So, can someone help me with why this happens exactly ?*** I am running the below code simply to extract some data from Yahoo Finance. I get the following ***set_index*** KeyError from time to time which references 3 separate, but similar lines (55, 93, & 131 to be exact, which i added comments next to):

```
File "/Users/daniel/Desktop/CG.py", line 55, in <module>
    df_balancesheet = df_balancesheet.set_index('0', drop=True, append=False,inplace=False, verify_integrity=False)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 4303, in set_index
    raise KeyError(f"None of {missing} are in the columns")
KeyError: "None of ['0'] are in the columns"
```

This error can happen 15 times in a row then suddenly the code works and runs smoothly...until it doesn't. Below is the majority of the code i am running:

```
from datetime import datetime
import lxml
from lxml import html
import requests
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from urllib.request import urlopen as ur
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup

print('Running Screen...')
collection  = ['ar=180','r=21&ar=180','r=41&ar=180','r=61&ar=180','r=81&ar=180','r=101&ar=180','r=121&ar=180','r=141&ar=180','r=181&ar=180','r=201&ar=180','r=221&ar=180','r=241&ar=180']
for url in collection: #scrape multiple pages
        my_url = 'https://finviz.com/screener.ashx?v=141&f=cap_smallover,fa_eps5years_pos,fa_grossmargin_o10,fa_netmargin_pos,fa_opermargin_pos,fa_sales5years_o5,geo_usa,sh_avgvol_o1000,ta_beta_o0.5&ft=2&' + str(url)
        uClient = ur(my_url)
        page_html = uClient.read()
        uClient.close()
        page_soup = soup(page_html, "html.parser") #find ticker
        stock_tickers = page_soup.findAll("a", {"class":"screener-link-primary"})
        for tickers in stock_tickers: #find all of the tickers
                ticker = tickers.text
                collection  = [ticker]
                for url in collection: #scrape multiple pages
                        #balance sheet data
                        my_url1 = 'https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/' + str(url) + '/balance-sheet?p=' + str(url) 
                        headers = {
                            'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3',
                            'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
                            'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.9',
                            'Cache-Control': 'max-age=0',
                            'Pragma': 'no-cache',
                            'Referrer': 'https://google.com',
                            'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/77.0.3865.120 Safari/537.36'
                        }
                        page = requests.get(my_url1, headers)
                        tree = html.fromstring(page.content)
                        tree.xpath("//h1/text()")
                        table_rows = tree.xpath("//div[contains(@class, 'D(tbr)')]")
                        #assert len(table_rows) > 0
                        parsed_rows = []
                        for table_row in table_rows:
                            parsed_row = []
                            el = table_row.xpath("./div")
                            none_count = 0
                            for rs in el:
                                try:
                                    (text,) = rs.xpath('.//span/text()[1]')
                                    parsed_row.append(text)
                                except ValueError:
                                    parsed_row.append(np.NaN)
                                    none_count += 1
                            if (none_count < 4):
                                parsed_rows.append(parsed_row)
                        df_balancesheet = pd.DataFrame(parsed_rows)
                        df_balancesheet = pd.DataFrame(parsed_rows)
                        df_balancesheet = df_balancesheet.set_index('0', drop=True, append=False,inplace=False, verify_integrity=False) ***#ERROR LINE 1***
                        df_balancesheet = df_balancesheet.transpose()
                        cols = list(df_balancesheet.columns)
                        cols[0] = 'Date'
                        df_balancesheet = df_balancesheet.set_axis(cols, axis='columns', inplace=False)
                        numeric_columns = list(df_balancesheet.columns)[1::]
                        #income statement data
                        my_url2 = 'https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/' + str(url) + '/financials?p=' + str(url) 
                        headers = {
                                'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3',
                                'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
                                'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.9',
                                'Cache-Control': 'max-age=0',
                                'Pragma': 'no-cache',
                                'Referrer': 'https://google.com',
                                'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/77.0.3865.120 Safari/537.36'
                        }
                        page = requests.get(my_url2, headers)
                        tree = html.fromstring(page.content)
                        tree.xpath("//h1/text()")
                        table_rows = tree.xpath("//div[contains(@class, 'D(tbr)')]")
                            #assert len(table_rows) > 0
                        parsed_rows = []
                        for table_row in table_rows:
                            parsed_row = []
                            el = table_row.xpath("./div")
                            none_count = 0
                            for rs in el:
                                try:
                                    (text,) = rs.xpath('.//span/text()[1]')
                                    parsed_row.append(text)
                                except ValueError:
                                    parsed_row.append(np.NaN)
                                    none_count += 1
                            if (none_count < 4):
                                parsed_rows.append(parsed_row)
                        df_incomestatement = pd.DataFrame(parsed_rows)
                        df_incomestatement = pd.DataFrame(parsed_rows)
                        df_incomestatement = df_incomestatement.set_index('0', drop=True, append=False,inplace=False, verify_integrity=False) ***#ERROR LINE 2***
                        df_incomestatement = df_incomestatement.transpose()
                        cols = list(df_incomestatement.columns)
                        cols[0] = 'Date'
                        df_incomestatement = df_incomestatement.set_axis(cols, axis='columns', inplace=False)
                        numeric_columns = list(df_incomestatement.columns)[1::]
                        # cash flow data
                        my_url3 = 'https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/' + str(url) + '/cash-flow?p=' + str(url) 
                        headers = {
                                'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3',
                                'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
                                'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.9',
                                'Cache-Control': 'max-age=0',
                                'Pragma': 'no-cache',
                                'Referrer': 'https://google.com',
                                'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/77.0.3865.120 Safari/537.36'
                        }
                        page = requests.get(my_url3, headers)
                        tree = html.fromstring(page.content)
                        tree.xpath("//h1/text()")
                        table_rows = tree.xpath("//div[contains(@class, 'D(tbr)')]")
                            #assert len(table_rows) > 0
                        parsed_rows = []
                        for table_row in table_rows:
                            parsed_row = []
                            el = table_row.xpath("./div")
                            none_count = 0
                            for rs in el:
                                try:
                                    (text,) = rs.xpath('.//span/text()[1]')
                                    parsed_row.append(text)
                                except ValueError:
                                    parsed_row.append(np.NaN)
                                    none_count += 1
                            if (none_count < 4):
                                parsed_rows.append(parsed_row)
                        df_cashflow = pd.DataFrame(parsed_rows)
                        df_cashflow = pd.DataFrame(parsed_rows)
                        df_cashflow = df_cashflow.set_index('0', drop=True, append=False,inplace=False, verify_integrity=False) ***#ERROR LINE 3***
                        df_cashflow = df_cashflow.transpose()
                        cols = list(df_cashflow.columns)
                        cols[0] = 'Date'
                        df_cashflow = df_cashflow.set_axis(cols, axis='columns', inplace=False)
                        numeric_columns = list(df_cashflow.columns)[1::]
                        writer = pd.ExcelWriter(ticker + '.xlsx')
                        df_incomestatement.to_excel(writer,'Income Statement')
                        df_balancesheet.to_excel(writer,'Balance Sheet')
                        df_cashflow.to_excel(writer,'Statement of Cash Flows')
                        writer.save()
                        print('Collecting data for ' + ticker + '...')
```

If you are able to shed some light on this, thank you in advance

Comment: first check data which you get from server - ie. display it to see it. Maybe server has some problem and it sends different data in different moments, Or it treats your script as dangerouse bot and it blocks access.

Comment: I thought perhaps the site was thinking i am a bot so i put a delay between each page request of 5 seconds, but unfortunately that provided no relief to the issue. is it possible that im simply sending too many requests and thus overwhelming the server? seems unlikely, but possible? idk

Comment: first you should check what you get in `page_html` - display it, or write in file and open in web browser. Maybe there is message which explains everything. BTW: real person rather doesn't not check pages with delay 5 seconds but much longer delay, and every delay will have different length. You may use `random` for this. If it is not enought then you may need proxy servers to send requests with different IP (and different User-Agent)

Comment: BTW: did you try tools like [yfinance](https://github.com/ranaroussi/yfinance) or [RapidAPI](https://rapidapi.com/blog/how-to-use-the-yahoo-finance-api/). Maybe they resolved problem with many requests in short time.